# Using jQuery, how do I pass arg to function and then display a message from predefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call this function, pass which type of error it is as an arg, and then display the message.

```
function msgDialog(msg) {
    // Define messages
    var errorMsg = "There has been an error.  We are sorry about that.";
    var loginMsg = "Something went awry with the login.  Please try again.";
    var uploadMsg = "Your upload failed.  Please try again.";
    var networkMsg = "You currently are not connected to the internet.  Please connect and try again.";
     alert(msg);
}
```

How do I call that function msgDialog(loginMsg) and have a var which I can assign to the correct message, then do something with that?  Here I am alerting it, but I will really display it differently.  I know that I need to create a new var with the value of the arg value, but not sure how.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Can you try to explain another way?

Comment: Yeah.  I want to call that function and I want to display a message depending on the argument sent.  For instance, if I called msgDialog(loginMsg), I want the alert to display "Something went ...", not just the arg var name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is pure JavaScript, no jQuery. Try this:

```
var msgDialog = (function() {
    var errors = {
        errorMsg : "There has been an error.  We are sorry about that.",
        loginMsg : "Something went awry with the login.  Please try again.",
        uploadMsg : "Your upload failed.  Please try again.",
        networkMsg : "You currently are not connected to the internet.  Please connect and try again."
    }

    return function(msg){
        alert(errors[msg]);
    }
})();

msgDialog('uploadMsg'); //  alerts "Your upload failed.  Please try again."
```

You can get an idea of what's going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) if you hadn't seen JavaScript closures before.

Comment: way cooler than what i would have said :).  can you post a usage statement?

Comment: OK yeah cool thanks.  And how do I call that var function?  For instance, I have other events going on, and on a failure of an event I want to call that msgDialog function from multiple other callbacks.

Comment: You can see a usage example in the last line of the code. Call it as every other function, passing the name of the message you want to display as a string.

Comment: Rocking good Nicolas.  Thank you.  Very clean and tight.  I bow down to your js kungfu, empty my cup and offer you a delicious beverage of your choice.

Comment: You're welcome. For more abstraction you can remove the "Msg" part from all the message names; they are redundant.  I mean calling msgDialog('error') instead of msgDialog("errorMsg").